# nodejs html script taken from database not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i have some some script which i saved in database for example-

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog-sidebar.html">Blog with sidebar</a></li>
  <li><a href="blogpost.html">Blog post</a></li>
  <li><a href="blogpost-sidebar.html">Blog post with sidebar</a></li>
</ul>
```

when i print it in html page using node js application, it simply print it as STRING , i want it to work like actual html script ( as it work in some other language like php  )

engine i am using to produce html page is flowing

```
app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/views"));
```

Comment: How are you inserting this text into the DOM? You will probably want to do something like `document.getElementById("yourParent").appendChild(yourHtmlNode); `. If your using jQuery this can be done by simply using the `append` method http://api.jquery.com/append/ e.g. `$("#myId").append("myHTMLString")`

Comment: i am using twig to to insert it in html page  and i am using mongodb database

Comment: I'm not familiar with twig, can you show me how you are including the html from the database. Just a couple of lines from your template.

Comment: as simply i am getting result from datatbase and rendering html page using node js return res.render('result-center',{items:items });  and printing  items in html page by {{ items }}

Answer (score 1):

According to the twig php documentation there is a raw filter [http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html](http://Twig%20Raw%20Filter) which will mark the content as safe.

So I would suggest trying

`{{ htmlResponseFromMongoDB | raw }}`

However the twig.js implementation does not appear to support this filter [https://github.com/justjohn/twig.js/wiki/Implementation-Notes](http://Twig.js%20Implementation%20Notes)

An alternative according to the docs is to turn off autoescape around that block.

```
{% autoescape false %}
{{item}}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you printing to html?
Try this:

```
app.get('/page1', function(req, res) 
{

    var fromdb = '<ul> \
    <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li> \
    <li><a href="blog-sidebar.html">Blog with sidebar</a></li> \
    <li><a href="blogpost.html">Blog post</a></li> \
    <li><a href="blogpost-sidebar.html">Blog post with sidebar</a></li> \
    </ul>';

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<html><head></head><body>');
    res.write(fromdb);
    res.end('</body></html>');

});
```

Comment: Not sure how your are doing it. It works for me. 
Code: https://jsfiddle.net/sumanvarma18/ya2yk3nz/
Image: http://i.imgur.com/9LDonFr.png?1

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me.......and yes I didn't vote you down.....nor do I have power to do ( as my reputation is less than 15 )